# How to add the HTML contents of one node to another with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

As the title says, I was wondering how to add the contents of one node to another so for example. Assume there is a node:

```
<li>
 <a>I'm a link</a>
 <p>I'm a <b>paragraph</b></p>
</li>
```

And another node I want to add the contents of to the above:

```
<p>
 <a>Link1</a>
 <a>Link2</a>
 <a>Link3</a>
 <a>Link4</a>
</p>
```

Then unload the latter node into the former like so:

```
<li>
 <a>I'm a link</a>
 <p>I'm a <b>paragraph</b></p>
 <a>Link1</a>
 <a>Link2</a>
 <a>Link3</a>
 <a>Link4</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created two HTML DOM Fragments based on your question. 
This line essentially combines `@doc.at_css("li") << @doc1.at_css("p").children` the two fragments.

The `@doc.at("li")` returns the DOM `Node` `li`. 
The `<<` appends the children of the @doc1 DOM ``` Node``p ``` which are the four `a` elements.

```
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse <<-EOHTML
<li>
 <a>I'm a link</a>
 <p>I'm a <b>paragraph</b></p>
</li>
EOHTML

@doc1 = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse <<-EOHTML
<p>
 <a>Link1</a>
 <a>Link2</a>
 <a>Link3</a>
 <a>Link4</a>
</p>
EOHTML

@doc.at("li") << @doc1.at("p").children
print @doc

<li>
 <a>I'm a link</a>
 <p>I'm a <b>paragraph</b></p>

 <a>Link1</a>
 <a>Link2</a>
 <a>Link3</a>
 <a>Link4</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Don't post code only. Instead, *explain* why it works. The difference is the handing out code doesn't help the user avoid the problem in the future, whereas explaining it helps them avoid it. Also, `at_css` can be reduced to `at` 99% of the time. *VERY* occasionally the selector is too generic and Nokogiri can't tell whether it's CSS or XPath.